# ObjC: ARC releasing dynamically created view controller too early

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

I have a view controller, named AllThingsViewController that dynamically creates other view controllers, named ThingViewController, and adds their top level view to a UIScrollView. (I'm writing proprietary code so I've changed the names of my classes, but the structure of my code is exactly the same.)

Here's what its loadView method contains:

```
NSArray *things = [[ThingDataController shared] getThings];

if ([things count] == 0) {
    // code in this block is not relevant as it's not being executed...
} else {

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < [things count]; ++i) {
        ThingViewController *thingViewController = [[ThingViewController alloc] init];
        [thingViewController loadView];

        [scrollView addSubview:thingViewController.topView];
        thingViewController.topView.frame = CGRectNewOrigin(thingViewController.topView.frame,
                0, thingViewController.topView.frame.size.height*i);

        [thingViewController displayThing:thing[i]];
    }
}
```

ThingViewController's loadView method looks like this:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    NSArray *topLevelObjs = nil;
    topLevelObjs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ThingView" owner:self options:nil];
    if (topLevelObjs == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: Could not load ThingView xib\n");
        return;
    }
}
```

When my app starts up everything displays correctly, until I try to tap one of the buttons that exists in the xib being loaded by ThingViewController, at which point it crashes due to an exception: "unrecognized selector sent to instance". It seems that ARC is releasing my ThingViewController instances too early.

Looking at my code, I figured it was because they weren't being held on to anything, so I created an NSMutableArray as an instance variable in my AllThingsViewController class, and started adding the ThingViewControllers to it thusly:

```
NSArray *things = [[ThingDataController shared] getThings];

if ([things count] == 0) {
    // not being executed...
} else {

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < [things count]; ++i) {
        ThingViewController *thingViewController = [[ThingViewController alloc] init];
        [thingViewController loadView];

        [scrollView addSubview:thingViewController.topView];
        thingViewController.topView.frame = CGRectNewOrigin(thingViewController.topView.frame,
                0, thingViewController.topView.frame.size.height*i);

        [thingViewController displayThing:thing[i]];

        [allThingsViewControllers addObject:thingViewController];
    }
}
```

However, it didn't change anything, even though those objects are being added to the array. Finally, just to confirm that this is ARC releasing it early, I changed "thingViewController" to be an instance variable in AllThingsViewController and changed:

```
ThingViewController *thingViewController = [[ThingViewController alloc] init];
```

to be:

```
thingViewController = [[ThingViewController alloc] init];
```

Sure enough, the last item in the scrollable list doesn't crash when I tap its buttons, but the other ones do, because its ThingViewController isn't being deallocated.

I'm still relatively new to ARC, but after a bunch of Googling I have no idea how to fix this. What do I do?

Comment: Please show the *complete* "unrecognized selector ..." error message.

Comment: Unrecognized selector errors usually don't indicate that something is released too early. What is the unrecognized selector it is complaining about?

Comment: A completely different object then my view controller is trying to respond to a selector when I tap a button. The research I've done suggests this is because the view controller is being released and a new object now inhabits that part of memory. Also, each time I run it's a different kind of object trying to perform the selector. Also also, if I explicitly make "thingViewController" be an instance variable (so that there's definitely a strong reference to it) it stops crashing for a least one of the view controllers, so I'm pretty sure the problem is it being released too early.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things.

**Problem 1:**

This looks like the cause of your bug:

```
[allBillViewControllers addObject:billViewController];
```

It should be:

```
[allBillViewControllers addObject:thingViewController];
```

Right?

**Problem 2**

You are not properly adding the view controller to your view hierarchy. It should be this:

```
[self addChildViewController:childViewController];
[childViewController.view setFrame:targetFrame];
[scrollView addSubview:childViewController.view];
[childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

And similarly when removing a child view controller:

```
[childViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[childViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[childViewController removeFromParentViewController];
```

**Problem 3**

Never call `loadView` explicitly on a view controller. It gets called by UIKit whenever you access the `view` property of a view controller.

**Problem 4**

You must add the `view` of the child view controller to your scroll view, not an arbitrary subview `topView` in its view hierarchy. Refactor your ThingViewController class to make this simpler for yourself. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at your code:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < [things count]; ++i) {
    ThingViewController *thingViewController = [[ThingViewController alloc] init];
    [thingViewController loadView];

    [scrollView addSubview:thingViewController.topView];
    thingViewController.topView.frame = CGRectNewOrigin(thingViewController.topView.frame,
            0, thingViewController.topView.frame.size.height*i);

    [billViewController displayThing:thing[i]];

    [allBillViewControllers addObject:billViewController];
}
```

After each loop of the for loop executes, nothing will have a strong reference to the `ThingViewController`.  Thus, it gets released and destroyed.

If `ThingViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, then it should be made a "child view controller" of the scrollview's view controller.  I recommend reading [the section on from the View Controller Programming Guide on creating custom container view controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) (i.e., a view controller that encapsulates and displays other view controllers).